# Change origin/pivot point without using 3D cursor (or basically the GUI)

Tags: python, objects, command-line, 3d-cursor

Is there a way we can change the origin or pivot point for a rotation/scaling activity in edit mode without using the 3D cursor, as I'm trying to run blender from a command-line without GUI and hence can't use 3D cursor.

Comment: how are you doing the transformations?

Comment: I want to scale a group of vertices, but the origin is at the global origin (0,0,0). When I just select the vertices and enter the scale command, the vertices are scaling with respect to the position from the origin, but I want them to scale with respect to the local origin (mean or geometric center of the selected vertices). So I want to shift the origin/pivot from global (0,0,0) to the geometric center of the selected vertices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this .. `bpy.context.scene.cursor_location = (0, 0, 0)` in edit and object mode.